# Docker with MongoDB (3.4) Replica Shard

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Using docker-compose to bring up a development mongo sharded cluster.  Development because each replica set and the config are single instances:

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rs1_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs1
  rs2_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs2
  config_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/db
  mongos_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongos --configdb rs1/config_n1:27017,
```

No issue bringing up the replica sets and the config.  The router (mongos) is failing with:  `Failed global initialization: FailedToParse: Empty host component parsing HostAndPort from ""`

As far as I can tell from the docs, I am passing the `<replicaset_name>/ip:port` argument correctly.  Is some additional information necessary because I am doing all of this within docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

default configsvr port is 27019.

try this instead:

`version: '2'
services:
  rs1_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs1
  rs2_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs2
  config_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/db
  mongos_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongos --configdb rs1/config_n1:27019`

or

`version: '2'
services:
  rs1_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs1
  rs2_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet rs2
  config_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/db --port 27017
  mongos_n1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongos --configdb rs1/config_n1:27017`

You may also be interested in the following image [khezen/mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/khezen/mongo/)